# jQuery onclick function needs a double click to initiate

Tags: jquery, drupal

I have a code snippet that's present twice on a node in drupal.

```
<a class="btn" href="http://#" onclick="jQuery(\'#login-form-holder\').slideToggle(200); return false;" >
```

I've been having a headache regarding that this snippet in one place needs only a normal click to initiate the slideToggle while the other one you have to click twice within the 200 ms timer for it to toggle.

What I'm wondering is what's causing it to require getting clicked twice within the time span and what a possible fix might be?

----EDIT----

```
$commentlogin = '<div class="test"><a class="btn" href="http://#" onclick="jQuery(\'#login-form-holder\').slideToggle(200); return false;" >Log In</a></div>';
```

Code that the drupal module uses to build up the whole commenting section.

-------UPDATE--------

The problem has been fixed, there was hidden in the code and event.stopPropagation that was watching for clicks outside certain elements to close the form, I needed to add the ID for this button to that list and the problem was fixed.

Comment: what happens if you don't escape the single quotes?  I don't see a need for escaping them in the code you've provided

Comment: If they aren't present it triggers the href which takes the user to a login page, instead of triggering the slideToggle effect.

Comment: `$commentlogin = '<div class="test"><a class="btn" href="http://#" onclick="jQuery(\'#login-form-holder\').slideToggle(200); return false;" >Log In</a></div>';`

This the variable that's used in the drupal module that build up the commenting section where it is used. This variable is then used later in conjuction with other to create the end product the user sees. The backslashes are used so that it recognizes to look for the id on the page to execute the slideToggle on.

Comment: Maybe add the click with jquery in drupal behaviors to make sure it works for ajax and after everything is loaded 
function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
      'attach': function (context) {
        $('.test .btn:not(.btn-processed)').addClass('btn-processed')
          .bind(
          'click', function (e) {
            $('#login-form-holder').slideToggle(200);
          }
        );
      }
    };
  }
)(jQuery);